# S3 keep entropy high for cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub user directory

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am authenticating each user via Cognito and each user has a folder everyone can read from but only he can write to it. Works like a charm.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadingOthers",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111:role/Cognito_Auth_Role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUploadIntoHomeDirectory",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111:role/Cognito_Auth_Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/user/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is the entropy for the folder names is very low since every folder starts with "us-east-1:", which can result in performance problems later on.
My workaround is to add additional entries with a "random" (aa-zz) start and add this to the database and the rules. Works too, but I want to avoid having that many rules for my bucket if possible.

```
"Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/user/aa${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
     "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/user/ab${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
     "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/user/ac${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
.
.
.
     "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/user/zy${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
     "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx/user/zz${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
]
```

Is there another way to add entropy with cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub?

Comment: Isn't there entropy right after `us-east-1:`?  It shouldn't matter *where* it is in the prefix, as long as there is a meaningful place where S3 can do a prefix split on the keyspace, e.g between `us-east-1:7fff` and `us-east-1:8000` such that half the future activity goes to each of the new partitions.  The potential performance issue comes from a hot spot that can't be relieved with automatic repartitioning -- e.g., when keys are lexically monotonic, there's nowhere that you can effectively split to relieve write contention, since new writes are always going to be higher than the split point.

Comment: Well, Amazon states in it's tech docs that the first couple chars should have max entropy, e.g. a time stamp is really bad (2013-10...) as stated e.g. here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FHRzq7eHQc.

Comment: I'm familiar with videos like that and documents like [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) which also mentions that *"you can optionally add more prefixes in your key name, before the hash string"* but intuition tells me they are somewhat over-emphasizing the point, which is really this, from the same doc: *"Again, the prefixes you add to group objects should not have sequences, or you will again overwhelm a single index partition."*  Lexically sequential keys seem to be the real issue.

Comment: Cool, thanks!! Can you add this an answer so I can upvote it?